# Use array to implement checkbox in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I make 10 or more than 10 check box by a for loop

This is my code

In view.html.erb

```
<% (0...100) do |i| %>
  <%= f.check_box :chkbox_ary[i], {:checked=>false, :style => "width: 20px; height: 20px;"} %>
  <%= f.label "checkbox" %>
<% end %>
```

And in model

```
attr_accessor :chkbox_ary

def initialize(attributes = {})
  @chkbox_ary = []
end
```

I think this is OK, but I always get error

```
Internal Server Error
expected Array (got Rack::Utils::KeySpaceConstrainedParams) for param `travel'
```

How can I do to get my purpose or have some reference for me?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop is missing an iterator:

```
(0...100).each do |i|
```

And you cannot use an index on a symbol - use the name of the array, and interpolate the index variable:

```
f.check_box "chkbox_ary[#{i}]" #...
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply and correction.
But how can I communicate with my attr_accessor in model.

"chkbox_ary[#{i}]" seem not means :chkbox_ary
Thanks

Comment: Your checkbox array is not part of an object, so you can't access it using the object referenced by your form helper `f`. Use this version instead, passing the tag name and value separately: `check_box_tag "chkbox_ary[#{i}]", @ckbox_ary[i], ...`

Comment: I'm so sorry, I still can't solve my problem.
When I use :ckbox_ary[0], it will show 'c'.

This is website I make.
http://www.taxifong.com/travel/travel.

I only want to use a attr_accessor to record checkbox value, and I will use notifier to send the mail.
<% if @sender.chkbox_ary[0] == "1" %> <%= test %> <BR><% end %>

My previous method is use many attr_accessor, but I think this is not good